# Simple ATM. Getting zeroes instead of transactions in ATM program

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have made a cash machine (ATM) program, but i can't figure out what is wrong. Everything is working except that the transactions are a line of zeroes. I must have messed something up.. I think it's is something to so with the "showTransactions" method. Thanks for help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ATM {
        private static int position = - 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Set a value to the various 
        int amount = 0;
        int choice = 0;
        int sum;
        int balance = 0;
        int[] trans = new int[10];

        while (choice != 4) {
            choice = menu();
            switch (choice) {

            case 1:
                System.out.print("How much would you like to deposit?: ");
                System.out.println();

                sum = input.nextInt();

                if (sum == 0) {
                    System.out.print("Unable to deposit");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                } else {
                    balance += sum;
                    makeTransactions(trans, amount);
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.print("How much would you like to withdraw?");
                System.out.println();

                sum = input.nextInt();

                if (sum == 0 || sum > balance) {
                    System.out.print("Unable to withdraw");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println();
                } else {
                    balance += - sum;
                    makeTransactions(trans, amount);
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                showTransactions(trans, balance);
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println("You chosed to end ");
                break;
            }

        }
    }

    public static int menu() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;

        System.out.println("Cash machine");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println("1 - Deposit            *");
        System.out.println("2 - Withdraw           *");
        System.out.println("3 - View transactions  *");
        System.out.println("4 - End cash machine   *");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");

        choice = input.nextInt();
        return choice;
    }

    public static void showTransactions(int[] trans, int balance) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Previous 10 transactions");
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++) {
            if(trans[i] != 0)
            {
                System.out.print(trans[i] + "\n");
            }

                else
                {
                    System.out.print(trans[i] + "\n");
                    balance = balance + trans[i];

                }

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Balance: " + balance + " kr" + "\n");
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static void makeTransactions(int[] trans, int amount) {
        int position = findNr(trans);
        if(position == -1)
        {
            moveTrans(trans);
                position = findNr(trans);
                trans[position] = amount;
        } 
        else {
            trans[position] = amount;
        }

    }

    public static int findNr(int[] trans) {
        int position = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < trans.length - 1; i++) {
            if (trans[i] == 0) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }

    public static void moveTrans(int[] trans) {
        for (int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++)
            trans[i - 1] = trans[i];

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the simplest input which reproduces this problem?  What do you see when you step through your code in your debugger?

Answer (score 1):

```
case 1:
            System.out.print("How much would you like to deposit?: ");
            System.out.println();

            sum = input.nextInt();

            if (sum == 0) {
                System.out.print("Unable to deposit");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
            } else {
                balance += sum;
                makeTransactions(trans, amount);
            }
            break;
```

In the above code, when you make call to `makeTransactions` method you are passing `amount` as parameter which you never change i.e. It is always 0. I think you should pass in `sum` as that is where you are storing the value of user input.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is saying that **IF trans[i] EQUALS 0 then print** why ? maybe change

```
if(trans[i] == 0)
```

to

```
if(trans[i] != 0)
```

or why not print them all, they're all part of the transaction anyways.

Comment: Also agree with @Sneh

Comment: Sorry i was trying some other options and forgot to change it.. My bad!